# Spring Boot 1.4 QueryDSL dependencies issue

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-data, querydsl

I have just updated from Spring Boot 1.3.6 to 1.4.0 and I'm getting the next problem:

The type `com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLQuery` cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

My pom.xml configuration is:

```
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
...

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.4</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-sql</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any clue?.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're trying to mix QueryDSL versions (3.7.4 and 4.1.3)? You should use 4.x across the board

Comment: They are two different groups com.mysema.querydsl and com.querydsl and  are used in two different modules. But the error still happens even removing com.querydsl (4.1.3) from my project . The class where the error occurs has this import "import com.mysema.query.jpa.JPQLQuery"

Comment: They are used in two different modules yet you didn't mention that in the question and have shown them in the same pom? Please stop wasting people's time and provide a minimal, accurate example that reproduces the problem

Comment: Sorry, I do not think I made myself clear. Both artifact are in the same pom.xml. That configuration works well in Spring Boot 1.3.6 but it does not in Spring Boot 1.4.0. Thanks for your time @AndyWilkinson

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I fixed my problem updating the querydsl-jpa 3.7.4 library to QueryDSL 4 (and modifying my code). It seems like Spring Boot 1.4 is not compatible with QueryDSL 3 anymore (as Spring Data JPA 1.10 upgraded to Querydsl 4).

Thanks.

Comment: I am also facing same problem. Can you please post here spring boot and query dsl jar version that  worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

For libraries that Spring Boot provides integrations you should use a BOM dependency. Basically having this in your pom/parent pom:

```
<dependencyManagement>
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And when you specify real dependencies, drop the version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-sql</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This guarantees compatibility since the BOM dependency is taking care of giving you the proper version.

More info [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent)

Answer (score 0):

Ulises's answer is correct and you could use

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

to mange the dependence as well. just check the [dependence version managed by spring boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html) for right **Group ID** and **Artifact ID**

Comment: How your answer is different from Ulises's answer  ?

Comment: I just want to mention another option of manage dependence with parent tag. Another reason to link the document is that group name  managed by spring boot  <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId> has already been changed to com.querydsl, so the best place to check this kind of information is the the link the document.